# Iterate and call methods inside array-like objects

Tags: javascript

I've got this object-structure and would like to iterate over all direct child objects of `obj` and call their `myMethod` method.
While `for...in` iterates over them correctly I always get this error `o.myMethod is not a function`

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqmdxc5e/1/)

```
obj = {
    test1: {
        "name": "test1string",
        "myMethod": function(){
            console.log("test 1 method called")
        }
    },
    test2: {
        "name": "test2string",
         "myMethod": function(){
            console.log("test 2 method called")
        }
    }
};

for (var o in obj) {
    console.log(o.name());
    o.myMethod();
}
```

**How can I achieve the wanted behaviour?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `o` in your `for` loop [corresponds to keys and not to values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Examples).

To get the value use [square-bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation): `obj[o].myMethod();`.

Answer (score 2):

`obj[o].myMethod()`. `for .. in` gives you names of members, not the values.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this `obj[o].name`. Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqmdxc5e/2/)